# Running a ClickOnce application on OSX without VMware, Parallells, Virtuabox,Bootcamp etc

Tags: mac, virtualization, vmware, boot-camp, clickonce

I run Ctrader which is a clickOnce application, and since there is no OSX version (nor any *nix version) I'm bound to running windows just for this.
I've tried Parallells, VMwareFusion, Virtuabox, Bootcamp, but it just used too much resources to run it smoothly even on my MBP 2,6 i7 16GB - once you open up a few instances, it just gets bulky and clunky, not something you'd want when fast execution makes the difference between wins or losses.
I've also tried Wine, Codeweavers crossover, WinOnX, and possible some other odd windows emulator, it all boils down to not being able to run the ClickOnce app once installed, or running into .Net dependency errors -Hell- I've tried to fix some errors, but I'm not a developper, and it just takes too much maintenance for it too be convenient or a considerable alternative to running a full OS virtualisation layer just for this program... I'm therefore appealing to the wisdom of the stackexchange superusers, hoping there is an option I have not found or tried to achieve running this decently on OSX ?  I havent followed virutalisation developments for the recent years, but could Kubernetes possibly be a solution ?   Looking forward to your inputs.  Much obliged, kind Sirs

Comment: "once you open up a few instances, it just gets bulky and clunky" Why would you need to run multiple instances of a Windows VM?  Run one and leave it running.

Comment: Boot Camp is going to be the single fastest way to run Windows on your Mac. It's not an emulator, it's running natively on your hardware. if that's too slow for you, you need a faster Mac.

Comment: @jamesdlin I only run a single instance of the Windows VM, it's the ClickOnce application i run multiple instances of, e.g. to connect to different broker or a different account.

Comment: @Tetsujin Understand what you're saying, and true indeed, but what I meant with Bootcamp, is running Windows directly off the hardware by booting the partition in Fusion. Running it directly off windows isn't the issue, that works fine, I just want it to work in OSX, and not needing to run windows anymore, be it directly or virtually.

Comment: If it won't run in Wine etc, then your choices are a VM or Bootcamp. That's it. I have Win10 running 24/7 in Parallels for some Win-only tasks. Laptops are not the ideal way to run heavy tasks, & 16GB RAM isn't enough to give you any freedom when half the machine is needed for the VM. I run mine on an old 8-core Mac Pro from 2008, with 32GB RAM. No problem at all. I don't even bother with a screen for it, I just remote into it, so it's 'always here', running in another Space.

Comment: @Sim If you run only a single VM, running additional instances of your application in that VM should not make it any bulkier and clunkier than on a physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer to OP, but I hope this helps anyone landing here after searching how to run a ClickOnce app under wine/Crossover.

This describes my experience of successfully installing & running a propitiatory ClickOnce app under Crossover 22 on an M1 MacBook Pro on macOS 13:

1. Install the Microsoft .Net Framework 4.7.2 into a new bottle
   This takes a while to complete due to installation of dependencies, services packs, etc. I used a Windows 10 64-bit bottle.
2. Install an unlisted application into the new bottle, then select the ClickOnce installer exe
3. The ClickOnce app installer runs, checks for updates, downloads, and opens the app.
4. The Crossover install process would not finish until the Deployment Fulfilment Service *dfsvc* was manually quit. This was launched by the installer, and performs the ClickOnce app update/download.
5. No app launcher was added.

The problem for me was the app installed and ran via Crossover 22, but there was no way to run the app again.

Browsing to the ClickOnce exe did kind of work, but after an update the location to the ClickOnce exe changes, and to run consistently the app installer must be run each time, which is not a great experience. An app launcher is needed.

---

**Create the app launcher/shortcut:**

Find the `.appref-ms` file for the app, e.g., `AppName.appref-ms`, which acts as the shortcut on a Windows system. This will call the Deployment Fulfilment Service *dfsvc* to run the ClickOnce app. The `.appref-ms` file contains the location where *dfsvc* checks for an update (web address or UNC).

The `.appref-ms` file was created as a Start menu item and located under `drive_c/users/crossover/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/`

The Start Menu location is where the Windows installer places shortcuts to programs, and where Crossover picks up app launchers.

Open the `.appref-ms` file with a text editor and copy the app URL/location.

In Crossover, with the new bottle selected, click *Run Command*, in the dialogue, browse to `rundll32.exe`, which is in the bottle's `drive_c\windows\system32` folder.

Append: `dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication`  + the download URL noted from the `.apppref-ms` file.

So that it looks similar to this:

`"/Users/user/Library/Application Support/CrossOver/Bottles/New Bottle/drive_c/windows/system32/rundll32.exe" dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbApplication https://downloadlink/AppName.application`

Click `Save command as a Launcher` and run the command. This creates a Windows `.lnk` containing the command in the Start Menu folder.

You will be able to use the link to launch you app at subsequent times without having to run the app installer.

---

As Crossover's app launcher is just a Windows `.lnk` file, it's possible to edit directly, which may be more convenient, rather than using the Crossover's *Run Command* to create the shortcut.

Here's a Windows Link file editor (works under wine):

https://github.com/ElektroStudios/Easy-Link-File-Viewer/releases

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer !